# Repairing linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

after last hard restart My linux broke and now I can't see icons on several folders, files and buttons. How can I fix these ?

In mozilla I can't see all icons like refresh or back.
In Applications menu I can't see icons next to first 7 elements.
How ever System tools, Universal access, Wine and ubuntu center have their icons.
There are also more cases like that in other menus and apps.

What can be solution ?

Comment: you really should give more informations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can Repair Linux ext2 or ext3 file system by doing following steps.

File system must be unmounted, you cannot repair it while it is running. Take system down to runlevel one (make sure you run all command as root user):

```
# init 1
```

Unmount file system, for example if it is /home (/dev/sda3) file system then type command:

```
# umount /home
```

OR

```
# umount /dev/sda3
```

Now run fsck on the partition:

```
# fsck /dev/sda3
```

However be sure to specify the file system type using -t option. Recenly one of our sys admin run the command on ext3 file system w/o specifying file system. Result was more corruption as fsck by default assumes ext2 file system.

```
# fsck -t ext3 /dev/sda3
```

OR

```
# fsck.ext3 /dev/sda3
```

fsck will check the file system and ask which problems should be fixed or corrected. If you don't wanna type y every time then you can use pass -y option to fsck.

```
# fsck -y /dev/sda3
```

Please not if any files are recovered then they are placed in /home/lost+found directory by `fsck` command.

4) Once fsck finished, remount the file system:

```
# mount /home
```

5) Go to multiuser mode

```
# init 3
```

Hope this would help

Comment: +1 for stating fsck assumes ext2 by default

Answer (score 1):

If one kernel of Linux is unstable, then you should be able to boot up into a slightly older, more stable one. I have mine set on dual-boot, so you always have to select which Linux kernel to use. If that's not your case, then you should be able to push one "F" buttons (e.g. F12) to pull up the bootup menu. You could also try booting up in safemode to try and fix the problem. Or it may just be a matter of restarting the system again...try just simply restarting, then if that fails try some of these other options.

Comment: It's not unstable. I don't see most of icons.

Comment: If your 'show desktop' setting were turned off, this will restore it:
Code:
gconftool-2 --type bool --set /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop 'true'                    *You have to logoff then log back on for this to take effect. This may fix your problem?

Comment: for example I can see icon next to Soun & Video

Answer (score 1):

I know that it could sound a little odd but you could delete your ~/.gnome, ~/.gnome2, ~/.nautilus and ~/.gconf with

> `rm -r ~/.gnome ~/.gnome2 ~/.nautilus
>   ~/.gconf`

to restore the settings to a default ubuntu's gnome.

If you have some configuration that you may want to put again in place, remember to do a backup: as simple as

> `cp -r ~/.gnome ~/.gnome2 ~/.nautilus ~/.gconf`

Comment: It doesn't work. I still can't see icons.